# How do I cancel my son's Xbox live? His xbox is broken and he put in a wrong email address

Tags: xbox-network

I am trying to figure out how to cancel an account that's coming out of my bank every month. His xbox is broken and he originally entered in a wrong email address. How can I cancel that?

Answer (score 21):

http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/billing/xbox-subscriptions/how-to-cancel-xbox-subscription should tell you everything you need to know, assuming you or your son can remember the account details (email/gamertag and password) used.

The relevant section is below:

> In a browser, sign in to the [Services & subscription](https://account.microsoft.com/services?refd=xboxsupport#) page with the Microsoft account that is associated with your subscription that you want to cancel.
>
> Note If you don't know your Microsoft account email address or password, use the [Lost Account Solution](http://support.xbox.com/my-account/microsoft-account/forgot-microsoft-account-solution) or the [Lost Password](http://support.xbox.com/my-account/microsoft-account/lost-password-solution) Solution.
> Find the Xbox subscription that you want to cancel, and then follow the instructions to cancel.

Answer (score 13):

The best bet is to contact Microsoft directly. Even with the wrong email address, you may tell with your credit card number what account to disable. Be prepared however to provide proof: Microsoft is known for their poor customer service.

They may also provide tips to find the email address linked to the credit card

Comment: Pretty much this. If Microsoft refuses to cancel the account using means you have available to verify (CC#, billing address, etc) and wants to confirm via (the wrong) email etc, you can always contact your credit card company and tell them to refuse payments to Microsoft... MS will cancel the subscription right quick if they're not getting money for it!

Comment: @DoktorJ I can confirm this is not the case re your last sentence, a friend of mine did this and had Microsoft demanding the monies paid as a debt 6 months later with threats of retrieval action. Just blocking the payment does not necessarily cancel the subscription.

Comment: @Vality If they have the wrong email address how will they contact you?

Comment: @CaptainMan By letter which they can likely send to the address the credit card is linked to.

Comment: "Microsoft is known for their poor customer service." it improved a lot in the last few years actually

Comment: What if you mark it as fraudulent? Wouldnt it be if you contact them and can't cancel due to lack of email?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this situation, we cannot mark the subscription as fraudulent since the kid has played on the account for maybe several months prior to the unsubscription demand. Also, if it was fraudulent, the owner of the credit card would have noticed the payments beforehand,

Comment: @Vality If you get a paper trail showing that you contacted Microsoft and requested cancellation and they continued to bill you prior to you stopping payment, then they can threaten collection all they want but if they attempt it you can haul them into court for harassment and provide documentation that you attempted all reasonable avenues of communication trying to cancel.